# where and how can I specify global vars in a reactjs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to define some global imports or vars to use them in all my files.

an example would be this

```
var T = require('react-redux-i18n').Translate;
```

at the moment I have to do this in all of my files. Is there a way to do this only once in the index.js?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not do it the classic javascript way with module.exports? i.e. in index.js do somthing like

```
var1 = '..';
var2 = '...';
...
module.exports= {var1, var2}
```

then in other files just do

```
import /path/to/index
...
console.log(index.var1)
console.log(index.var2)
```

or to import only what you need do

```
import {name_of_var_i_need} from /path/to/index
...
```

although I would suggest doing this in a constants.js file or something like that instead of having them all in your index.js (unless of course they need to be initialize in index)

Comment: This is how I'd choose to do it - it's also worth noting that once you import something it gets cached, so if you have to do some heavy lifting to initialize one of the constants, it'll only happen once, which is nice.

Comment: hm but If I do this all the stuff from index.js will be included? also the render stuff?

Comment: the stuff you choose to put in module.exports{} will be included yes. If you want to only import stuff you need from index.js you can just do something like import {var1} from '/path/to/index' and that will just import var1, ill update the example above

Comment: You don't need to literally put this in `index.js`. You can call your module anything. `mythings.js` for example. And import it from other files. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can put any globals on the `window` object and then read from it. This is generally considered a bad practice because it's confusing and doesn't work with optimization techniques like code splitting.

My advice: don't try to save keystrokes like this. Copying a few imports to every file you use them in is not a big deal, and makes program easy to understand both for you and for different tools. You can hack around it but in the end it won't be worth it.

Comment: yeah copy those 5 lines which should be imported ist not a big deal but is it the way its normally done in react?

Comment: Yes, just like in most programing languages with support for modules :-). It is not specific to React. If you want something to be available in a module, you need to import that in that module.